# how to manually assign imagefield in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that has an ImageField. How can I manually assign an imagefile to it? I want it to treat it like any other uploaded file...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See the django docs for [django.core.files.File](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.save)

Where fd is an open file object:

```
model_instance.image_field.save('filename.jpeg', fd.read(), True)
```

Comment: If you have to manually temper with files, for example you download an image, this extension may come handy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19476403/635636

Comment: model_instance.image_field.save('filename.jpeg', <file>, True) worked for me