# Django SuspiciousOperation at /upload/ when uploading a file

Tags: python, django

I'm  developing a project in `Django 1.5` and `Python 2.7`.
While uploading a file Django raise an error message:

**SuspiciousOperation at /upload/**

**Attempted access to '\static\file\test_file.txt' denied.**

This is the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/

Django Version: 1.5
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'app_is')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Adriano\Desktop\site_is\app_is\views.py" in upload_file
  81.             new_file.save()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  546.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  650.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in _insert
  215.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in insert_query
  1673.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  936.         for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
  894.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in pre_save
  250.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in save
  86.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in save
  47.         name = self.get_available_name(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in get_available_name
  73.         while self.exists(name):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in exists
  243.         return os.path.exists(self.path(name))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py" in path
  259.             raise SuspiciousOperation("Attempted access to '%s' denied." % name)

Exception Type: SuspiciousOperation at /upload/
Exception Value: Attempted access to '\static\file\test_file.txt' denied.
```

This is the HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

this is the form:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    middleschool = 'MS'
    highschool = 'HS'
    university = 'U'
    blank = '-'

    school_choices = ((middleschool, 'Middle School'), (highschool, 'High school'), (university, 'University'), (blank, 'Not defined'),)

    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 30, required = True)
    file = forms.FileField()
    description = forms.CharField(max_length = 140, required = False, label='Breif description of the files content')
    school = forms.ChoiceField(choices = school_choices, required=False, label='What level is the material that are you uploading?', initial = blank)
    subject = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subject.objects.order_by('?'), required=False, label='What subject this file is about?')
    price = forms.FloatField(required=False)
```

this is the view:

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_file = File(file = request.FILES['file'])
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            new_file.name = cd['name']
            new_file.description = cd['description']
            new_file.school = cd['school']
            new_file.subject = cd['subject']
            new_file.price = cd['price']
            new_file.rating = '0.0'
            new_file.user = request.user
            new_file.save()
            form = Search()
            return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form, 'request': request})
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form, 'request': request})
```

and this is the File's model:

```
class File(models.Model):
    middleschool = 'MS'
    highschool = 'HS'
    university = 'U'
    blank = '-'

school_choices = ((middleschool, 'Middle School'), (highschool, 'High school'), (university, 'University'), (blank, 'Not defined'),)

name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
description = models.CharField(max_length = 140, blank=False, null=False)
school = models.CharField(max_length = 30, choices = school_choices, default = blank)
subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=0, default = 0)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, default = 0, blank=True, null=True)
file = models.FileField(upload_to= "/static/file/")
```

My app path is: `C:/Users/User/Desktop/site_is/app_is/` and I want hose files saved in the folder: `C:/Users/User/Desktop/site_is/app_is/static/file/`. In my `Setting.py` I set:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/site_is/app_is/static/file/'
MEDIA_URL = '/file/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/site_is/app_is/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Since I'm a beginner in Django i fear that i mssed up the media/static root and/or url and this results in the error raised.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Related?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950069/suspicious-operation-django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line in your models:

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to= "/static/file/")
```

You are passing an absolute path, which would mean "store this in C:\static\file\", which is not a subdirectory of your `MEDIA_ROOT`. You can change the `upload_to` parameter either to an absolute path that starts with `C:/Users/User/Desktop/site_is/app_is/static/file/`, or a relative path:

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to= ".")
```

Comment: as `upload_to` is appended to `media_root`, and from OP formulation where he want to save files, it seems it should be `models.FileField(upload_to= ".")`