# Django: Saving a file from disk with FileField

Tags: django

In my app I parse some xml which contains a path to an image file. Now if I am passing the path to the property of my model which is a FileField it's not copying the file using the upload_to settings. I also tried to pass it a stream of that file but that raised an exception.

How do I use the FileField with data that isn't coming from a request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically saving image to Django ImageField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file is in your `MEDIA_ROOT` (If it's outside of `MEDIA_ROOT` you'll get `SuspiciousOperation` errors):

```
m = YourModel(file='uploads/file.txt')
```

If you already have the file on your system, it'd surely be easier to just move it to your uploads directory. You could always customize `FileField` to handle moving the file for you.

Comment: Does that mean if the file isn't in the MEDIA_ROOT I have to manually move it myself first? Means I would be recreating the upload_to logic which isn't very DRY.