# How to crop image on django admin side?

Tags: django, image, crop

I want to add a feature for image cropping in django admin site. I have no idea about that how could I approach this to get it done. I have used django-image-cropping application, but not able to integrate this for admin side.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907803/django-app-for-image-crop-using-a-cropping-tool .

Comment: have gone through this but not have an idea to implement in django admin side.

Comment: You need to go back and accept some answers for your previous 8 questions

Comment: "not able to integrate" is ... not really precise.

If you are using django 1.4 you have to use the latest version (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-image-cropping) as it includes some necessary fixes. Otherwise you have to give more information about what's going wrong. As image-cropping was designed for cropping images in the admin you don't really have to *integrate* it. Just follow the docs.

Comment: thanks to all for your valuable suggestion... I have done it using django-cropper app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define save() method in your model:

```
class MyImage(models.Model):
  image = models.ImageField(...)
  image_crop = models.ImageField(blank=True)

  def save():
    super(MyImage, self).save() #will save only image, image_corp will be blank.

    image_path = self.image.path #path to your non croped image

    #now you can load image file and crop it usung PIL and save.

    self.image_crop = 'path/to/cropped/image' #add path to cropped image.
    super(MyImage, self).save() #save data.
```