# Confused about Django file upload locations

Tags: python, django, file-upload

When working with manual file uploads, do I need to place the file in the final location before saving it to the model? Or, does the model move the file at some point? If I do need to place it myself, why do I need the `upload_to` param in the model field? That seems like I would have to keep parity with the `upload_to` param and the logic I'm using to copy it.

I think I'm just confused. Can someone help me do this right?

**My form gets in image url from the web:**

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):    
    main_image_url = forms.URLField()
    # etc...
```

**My view retrieves it, checks it, and makes a thumbnail:**

```
main_img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
main_img_temp.write(urllib2.urlopen(main_image_url).read())
main_img_temp.flush()

img_type = imghdr.what(main_img_temp.name)
if not img_type:
    errors = form._errors.setdefault("main_image_url", ErrorList())
    errors.append(u"Url does not point to a valid image")
    return render_to_response('add_image.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

# build a temporary path name
filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
dirname  = os.path.dirname(main_img_temp.name)
full_size_tmp  = os.path.join(dirname, filename+'_full.jpg')
thumb_size_tmp = os.path.join(dirname, filename+'_thumb.jpg')

shutil.copy2(main_img_temp.name, full_size_tmp)
shutil.copy2(main_img_temp.name, thumb_size_tmp)

# build full size and thumbnail
im = Image.open(full_size_tmp)
im.thumbnail(full_image_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save(full_size_tmp, "JPEG")

im = Image.open(thumb_size_tmp)
im.thumbnail(thumb_image_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save(thumb_size_tmp, "JPEG")

# close to delete the original temp file
main_img_tmp.close()


### HERE'S WHERE I'M STUCK. This doesn't move the file... ####
main_image = UploadedImage(image=full_size_tmp, thumbnail=thumb_size_tmp)
main_image.save()
```

**In my models, I've got an UploadedImage model that has the basic fields:**

```
class UploadedImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/images/%Y/%m/%d/full')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/images/%Y/%m/%d/thumb/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answered My Own Question...**

When I passed the path to the ImageField in the model, I was just handing it a path. I see now that to invoke all the storage handling built in to Django, you have to hand it a `File` object. This was enough to make it copy to the `upload_to` path:

```
from django.core.files import File

main_image = UploadedImage(image=File(open(full_size_tmp)), thumbnail=File(open(thumb_size_tmp)), creator=request.user)
main_image.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you save the model, it writes the files to the location that points `upload_to`. It handles that by itself so you won't need to do it manually.

Here you are writing the file to a temp, moving it after and a lot of things that can be done automatically. Check the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield) where he also uses `urllib` to get an image and save it into the db.

Note that you can pass a buffer in memory to create a `FileField` or `ImageField` which be suitable to do the logic for the thumbnail. Also you may consider using `django-thumbnails` for this purposes. It's a good library.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for jumping in. I'll look into condensing this and handing it an in-memory object.