# python - AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute '__committed'

Tags: python, django, urllib

I am trying to read image from url and save it to model. but i am getting this error message:

```
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute '__committed'
```

this is my code:

```
location = Location()
location.save()
image = urllib.urlopen(img_url)
location.locations_image.create(bild=image)
```

I guess, i am doing something wrong while reading an image file from url. can someone pls guide me? thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically saving image to Django ImageField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield)

Comment: @AamirAdnan, thanks Amir, nice answers out there, we could close mine