# how to display image to template from imagefield in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

My template cannot display the image coming from my model.

src attribute comes with proper field but it does not display the proper image

template:

```
       <div class="grid-product">
  
    {% for p in prod %}
    
    
    <div class="  product-grid">
        <div class="content_box"><a href="single.html">
        <div class="left-grid-view grid-view-left">
             <img  class="img-responsive watch-right" alt="not found" src="{{p.photo}}"/>
                <div class="mask">
                    <div class="info">Quick View</div>
                </div>
              </a>
        </div>
            <h4><a href="#"></a></h4>
             <p>It is a long established fact that a reader{{ p.p_name }}</p>
             Rs. 499
        </div>
   </div>
    {% endfor %} 
         <div id="show"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
</div>
```

model:

```
class product(models.Model):
    p_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ps_id=models.ForeignKey(alphasubcat,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    p_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='productimage',blank=True)
    price=models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.p_name
```

view:

```
def produc(request):
    param=dict()
    cat=categories.objects.all()
    sub=subcategories.objects.all()
    temp=request.GET['p']
    prod=product.objects.filter(ps_id=alphasubcat.objects.get(as_name=temp))
    param['prod']=prod
    param['cat']=cat
    param['sub']=sub
    return render(request,"product.html",param)
```

Comment: is p.p_name value coming on the html page?

Comment: yes it is displaying

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically saving image to Django ImageField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can access image url by `{{p.photo.url}}`. but as here in your model:

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='productimage, blank=True)
```

(blank=True) you would want to use something like:

```
<img  class="img-responsive watch-right" alt="not found" src={% if p.photo %}"{{p.photo.url}}"{% else %}"/something/else.png"{% endif %}/>
```

Comment: nice shot. One question: I get `tag start is not closed` as syntax error after closing quotes of `"{{p.photo.url}}"`. Any ideas?

Comment: @chefarov it might be a simple mismatch of opening and closing quotes as you know quotes also behave as brackets. If you can share your code, I can look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to

```
 <img  class="img-responsive watch-right" alt="not found" src="{{p.photo.url}}"/>
```

Comment: What is displayed in the `src` in the html source?

Comment: my settings.py file details

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static_cdn")

MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"src/media")
MEDIA_URL="/img/"

Comment: what does `{{ STATIC_URL }}` display?

Comment: Does the image display if you go to /img/productimage/pic3.jpg?

Comment: /home/lcom52/Desktop/happydeal/static_cdn
{{ STATIC_URL }}

Comment: @ilse2005 no it's not displaying

Comment: but from admin interface if i try to upload image by this model imagefield than it's succesfully uploaded

Comment: Looks like your MEDIA settings are wrong. What if you go to `/img/img/productimage/pic3.jpg`

Comment: what you suggest for MEDIA setting

Comment: okay , i tried it
is there any other available which easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

On your local server

```
<img  class="img-responsive watch-right" alt="not found" src="127.0.0.1:8000/{{p.photo.url}}"/>
```

thats fine settings in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 

STATICFILES_DIRS=[ os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"), ] 

STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static_cdn") 

MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"src/media")

MEDIA_URL="/img/" –
```

but also debug that STATIC_ROOT is return domain/link-to-image

Answer (score 0):

this is work for my problem
here static is my root folder for media file

```
img  class="img-responsive watch-right" alt="not found" src="static/{{p.photo}}"
```