# Manually trigger image save method in Django model

Tags: django, image, model, save, field

I have a Django model with a customized image field. The image field creates some thumbnail sizes on upload. Code may look like this:

```
from django.db import models
from utils import CustomImageField

class Photo(models.Model):
    image = CustomImageField()
```

Now I modify the original image, let's say I rotate it. And now I want to trigger the save method of my image field again, in order to overwrite the thumbnails and create rotated versions. So, I don't need to rotate the thumbnails elsewhere in my code (DRY).

Any thoughts? Something along those lines - but how exactly?

```
p = Photo.objects.get(pk=1)
p.image.save(...)
```

I have full control over the `CustomImageField` widget. The `save()` method is defined as:

```
def save(self, name, path, save=True):
```

Question is, what do I use for the methods parameters?

Comment: Can you not just call p.save() ?

Comment: No, this won't recall the image field's save method. If it did, that would be extremely inefficient in most cases.

Comment: Not enough to go by. You ought to post your CustomImageField

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Shall we tell you what arguments to pass to a method you created and which we don't know what it does? Who better than you knows that? Could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question looks like a duplicate of [Programmatically saving image to Django ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield)

The parameters of the `ImageField.save()` method are documented for `FileField.save()` (of which `ImageField` is a subclass):
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save

> Takes two required arguments: **name** which is the name of the file, and
>   **content** which is an object containing the file’s contents. The
>   optional **save** argument controls whether or not the model instance is
>   saved after the file associated with this field has been altered.
>   Defaults to **True**.

---

Here is what is working for us:

```
class CustomImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path, max_length=500)
    orig_name = models.TextField()
```

This is the method that adds an image file to the ImageField from an http resource:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

def download_photo(amazon_id, url):
    img_data = requests.get(url)
    img = CustomImage(orig_name=img_data.url)
    img.image.save(slugify(img.orig_name), ContentFile(img_data.content), save=True)
```

It also works without ContentFile:

```
new_img = File(open(different_obj.image.path), 'r')
img.image.save(different_obj.image.url, new_img, save=True)
```

See also:
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/files/
- https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2587/

Answer (score 2):

An option is dirty field checking, either manually (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355150/django-when-saving-how-can-you-check-if-a-field-has-changed)) or using a [pypi package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dirtyfields/)

Alternatively, if you want to conserve memory, the resizing can be triggered from the field's property setter (assuming you inherit from [`FileField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/db/models/fields/files.py)

```
class CustomImageField(FileField):

    def _set_file(self, file):
        has_file_changed = file != self._file
        super(CustomImageField, self)._set_file(file)
        if has_file_changed:
             self.handle_resizing_etc()

    # need to redeclare property so it points to the right _set_file
    file = property(FileField._get_file, _set_file, FileField._del_file)
```

*disclaimer: I haven't used this approach in production code and I haven't written a proof of concept before posting this answer, so it might not work as desired*