# Store Image in django

Tags: python, django

I want to store the imaage in django but unable to do it. This is what i tried..

upload.html

```
<form name="saveImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'Reports:saveimage'%}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div style = "max-width:470px;">

        <center>
            <input type = "file" style = "margin-left:20%;"
                   placeholder = "Picture" name = "picture" />
             <input type="submit" value="Store"></input>
        </center>
    </div>

</form>
```

model.py

```
def vo_image_upload(inatance,filename):
    return os.path.join('Volunteer',filename)

class Volunteer(models.Model):
    myphoto = models.ImageField(db_column='MyPhoto', upload_to=vo_image_upload, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def saveimage(request):
    image= request.FILES['picture']
    vo = Volunteer.objects.using('NSS_VO').update(myphoto=image).
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Success</h1>")
```

Update is used because I am storing image after registration.
This code is only saving the File name to `myphoto` field in database but not storing the image in `media` folder of `Project/project/media/`.

Project/Project/url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url ,include
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^ReportsData/', include('Reports.urls')),
    ]

    if settings.DEBUG :
        urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and above upload.html ,views.py , models.py belongs to app Reports.
What changes I have to do to store the images successfully

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically saving image to Django ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with `update()`, as that operates on the database only and wouldn't do any of the actual file saving. You must get the object, assign the file field, and save:

```
vo = Volunteer.objects.using('NSS_VO').get(id=whatever)
vo.myphoto=image
vo.save()
```