# How to make image gallery from zip archive in wagtail?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wagtail

I have a project and i have idea to make `wagtail` `Page` where user can upload an `zip` archive of images in the admin section. And then I want to unzip this archive and put each unzipped image to Image Gallery connected to this page:

```
import urllib.parse
import os
import zipfile

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page, Orderable
from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, InlinePanel
from wagtail.wagtailsearch import index
from wagtail.wagtailimages.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.wagtailimages.models import Image
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager

from .forms import PhotoEventPageForm
from utils import get_paginated_pages, get_all_tags

...

class PhotoEventPage(Page):
    photos = models.FileField(upload_to=directory_path)
    photos_unpacked = models.BooleanField(default=False)    
    ...

    base_form_class = PhotoEventPageForm

    def main_image(self):
        gallery_item = self.gallery_images.first()
        if gallery_item:
            return gallery_item.image
        else:
            return None

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if os.path.isfile(self.photos.path) and not self.photos_unpacked:
            with zipfile.ZipFile(self.photos.path, "r") as zip_ref:
                for file_name in zip_ref.namelist():
                    zip_ref.extract(
                        file_name,
                        path=os.path.dirname(self.photos.path))
                    # now i have image file, this line prints True:
                    # print(os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(self.photos.path), file_name)))
                    # so now I have saved image and i want to create Image gallery,
                    # I've tried this code:

                    # img = Image()
                    # img.save()
                    # gallery_img = PhotoEventPageGalleryImage(
                    #     image_id=img.id, page_id=self.id)
                    # gallery_img.save()

                    # but it's not working
            self.photos_unpacked = True
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class PhotoEventPageGalleryImage(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(PhotoEventPage, related_name='gallery_images')
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+'
    )
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)

    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('caption'),
    ]
```

But It's not working, I dont know how to create `wagtail.wagtailimages.models.Image` instance from my unzipped image, when  i uncoment this piece of code:

```
img = Image()
img.save()
gallery_img = PhotoEventPageGalleryImage(
                image_id=img.id, page_id=self.id)
gallery_img.save()
```

i'm getting `NOT NULL constraint failed: wagtailimages_image.width`. So maybe there is a way to do it?

After some googling, thanks to Paulo Scardine, also checked:
[this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wagtail/Get0wrrJ-3c)
I came up with following code:

```
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile

from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page, Orderable
from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, InlinePanel
from wagtail.wagtailsearch import index
from wagtail.wagtailimages.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.wagtailimages.models import Image
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase

...

class PhotoEventPage(Page):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if os.path.isfile(self.photos.path) and not self.photos_unpacked:
            with zipfile.ZipFile(self.photos.path, "r") as zip_ref:
                for file_name in zip_ref.namelist():
                    zip_ref.extract(
                        file_name,
                        path=os.path.dirname(self.photos.path))
                    # print(os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(self.photos.path), file_name)))

                    image_file = open(
                        os.path.join(
                            os.path.dirname(
                                self.photos.path), file_name), "rb")

                    image = Image(
                        title="Image title",
                        file=ImageFile(image_file, name=file_name),
                    )

                    image.save()
                    image_file.close()

                    gallery_img = PhotoEventPageGalleryImage(
                        image_id=image.id, page_id=self.id)
                    gallery_img.save()

            self.photos_unpacked = True
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And it's strange, i mean it's indeed working without errors and I can save `PhotoEventPage` without errors and images are extracted, but there is no any items inside `self.gallery_images` after saving, don`t know why.

Comment: Possibly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield (I suppose wagtail is Django under the hood)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to create `wagtail_hooks.py` file, and ,as said in the [docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/reference/hooks.html#id18), define hooks there:

**models.py**:

```
from wagtail.images.models import Image
...

class ExtenedWagtailImage(Image):
    filepath = models.FilePathField()


class PhotoEventPageGalleryImage(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(PhotoEventPage, related_name='gallery_images')
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        ExtenedWagtailImage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+'
    )
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)

    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('caption')
    ]
```

**wagtail_hooks.py**:

```
import os
import zipfile

from django.core.files.images import ImageFile
from django.db import IntegrityError

from wagtail.core import hooks

from .models import PhotoEventPageGalleryImage, ExtenedWagtailImage as EWI


@hooks.register('after_edit_page')
@hooks.register('after_create_page')
def create_gallery(request, page):
    if page.__class__.__name__ == 'PhotoEventPage':
        with zipfile.ZipFile(page.photos.path, "r") as zip_ref:
            for file_name in zip_ref.namelist():

                image_file_path = os.path.join(
                    os.path.dirname(page.photos.path), file_name)

                if not os.path.isfile(image_file_path):
                    zip_ref.extract(
                        file_name,
                        path=os.path.dirname(page.photos.path))

                with open(image_file_path, "rb") as image_file:
                    try:
                        image_obj, created = EWI.objects.get_or_create(
                            filepath=image_file_path,
                            defaults={
                                'file': ImageFile(image_file, name=file_name),
                                'title': file_name}
                        )
                    # if it's not an image
                    except IntegrityError:
                        continue

                photo_event_amount = len(
                    PhotoEventPageGalleryImage.objects.filter(
                        page_id=page.id, image_id=image_obj.id))

                if created or photo_event_amount == 0:
                    PhotoEventPageGalleryImage(
                        image_id=image_obj.id, page_id=page.id).save()
```