# Load data that has models with ImageField in django

Tags: python, django, fixtures, factory-boy

Any idea how to load data that has models with `ImageField` in django?
I cannot use fixtures for this as there’s no way to serialize images into the fixtures files.

I’m trying to use `factory-boy` which works very well for tests but I cannot see how to run it as a standalone script because there’s no django management command for it.

Is `python manage.py shell < myscript.py` a good approach to handle this or there’s a better way?

Note that I’m using a bucket for file storage with salted filenames, and I have signals that do stuff like indexing into Elasticsearch which I need to keep. and fixtures don’t do this.

Comment: Do you have your image file in place and know filename in advance?

Comment: @Slam No. I'm using salted filenames using `uuid` and I'm planing to download random images from the internet using https://source.unsplash.com/random

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield . Does it fit your case?

Comment: Not really, I don't have problem with storing image programmatically. the only problem is how I can run my script within the context of the django app and still benefit from the functionalities I wrote in post save signals.
I think I should create a management command for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the question is actually about having django env for your script, I've misunderstood the question.

1. You may use `shell < script.py`, viable one-timer
2. Make your custom management command. Ok if this is something regular, main benefit is "maintainability" — intention will be more clear for other people, plus `manage.py` integrations with IDE may be good
3. Your script may setup django env itself — same as `manage.py shell` does, there's not much of black magic, something like

   ```
   import os, django
   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
   django.setup()
   ```

Comment: The 3rd option looks good, I can also do it this way https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage
But I think I'll go with creating a management command because I'll probably need to add some args to customize the script.

Comment: Yup, if writing command is not a big deal for you, it worth going that way