# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_committed'

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='attack_images', blank=True, null=True)
    source_url = models.URLField(blank=True,null=True)
    domain = models.ForeignKey(Domain, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True,null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)[:50]

        if self.source_url and not self.image:
            result = urllib.request.urlretrieve(self.source_url)
            self.image = os.path.basename(self.source_url), File(open(result[0], 'rb'))

        if self.source_url:
            if '//' in self.source_url:
                d = self.source_url.split('//')[1].split('/')[0]
            else:
                d = self.source_url.split('/')[0]

            try:
                domain = Domain.objects.get(domain_url=d)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                domain_object = Domain.objects.create(domain_url=d)
                domain = domain_object
            self.domain = domain

        return super(AttackImage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("attack_image_detail", kwargs={
            'pk': str(self.id),
            'slug': str(self.slug)})
```

I believe this happens because of the line `self.image = os.path.basename(self.source_url), File(open(result[0], 'rb'))`

Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance. Stack is python/django. My basic question is, if I am correct, and the line above is what is causing the problem, how do I assign an image to an ImageField properly (without saving it)?

Comment: Please show us the code around `File "crawl_ebaumsworld.py", line 66, in crawl creator=mike`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically saving image to Django ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield)

Comment: seems this line causing the error, `self.image = os.path.basename(self.source_url), File(open(result[0], 'rb'))`.

Comment: Is that `open()` the standard Python function? If so, I suggest using a context manager. Is `File` imported from a library, or something you created?

Comment: @2ps no. see >(without saving it) in my question. Alexander, File imported from a Django module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with `ImageField` or `FileField` you actually operate on instance of [FieldFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile)

And error in this case is assigning wrong type to `ImageField` - it expects [FieldFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile) or at least [File](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/files/file/#the-file-class) type.

---

Brief answer what can be used instead of `self.image = ....` in your code:

```
from django.core.files import File

...

with open(result[0], "rb") as downloaded_file:
    self.image.save(os.path.basename(self.source_url), File(downloaded_file), save=False)
...
```

---

Check [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield) on saving files. I added a small change - **`save=False`** - while saving image - at this step we only save downloaded file = copying it from temporary path, where it was downloaded by urllib to desired target path in `MEDIA`, but **not saving model instance**.

`self.image.save(name, file)` - file is read and saved in `MEDIA` at `upload_to` path with name `name` and model instance is saved aftewards (default save=True).

`self.image.save(name, file, save=False)` - the same, but model instance is not saved after the file has been altered, which is probably desired as you save model instance `super().save()` later.

---

What steps are happening in your code:

- downloading file with urllib (to temp path)
- saving it / copying to correct media / upload_to path and setting ImageField to its value
- setting other model instance fields
- saving model