# Django ImageField object not updating with input field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I tried updating a user's profile picture using a function view (ajax) but I keep getting the error below:

**raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'emp_photo'**

The same technique I am using is being used on CharField and TextField without issues.

Please see below for my codes.

## views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
@user_passes_test(user_type_combo)
def change_employee_photo(request, pk):
    data = dict()
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmployeePhotoForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            newPic = profile(emp_photo=request.FILES['emp_photo'])
            newPic.save()
            data['is_valid'] = True
    else:
        form = EmployeePhotoForm(instance=profile)
        data['form_is_valid'] = False

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string('employees/partial_employee_photo.html',
                                         context,
                                         request=request
                                         )
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

## forms.py

```
class EmployeePhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['emp_photo',]


{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<form action="{% url 'change_employee_photo' form.instance.pk %}" class="js-change-employee-photo-form"
      enctype="multipart/form-data" id="ProfileUpdateForm" method="post" runat="server">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Change Employee Photo</h5>
        <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <div id="emp_photo_holder">
                <img alt="{{profile.first_name}}_{{profile.last_name}}" height="200px" id="emp_img"
                     src="/media/default.jpg/" width="200px"/>
                <input id="emp_photo" name="emp_photo" type="file" value="{{profile.emp_photo}}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

                function readURL(input) {
                  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function(e) {
                      $('#emp_img').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    }

                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                  }
                }

                $("#emp_photo").change(function() {
                  readURL(this);
                });


        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning confirmation"
                onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want upload a new photo for this employee?')"
                type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

I will most definitely appreciate any help to have this issue resolved.

Comment: I guess the problem lies over here `newPic = profile(emp_photo=request.FILES['emp_photo'])` as you are updating the profile image you can try `profile.emp_photo.save('filename', fdata, True)`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60049358/8601641) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

i Guess you have forgot to mention the below lines in your settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

Comment: This is not the case. My media path has no issue

Comment: newPic = profile(emp_photo=request.FILES['emp_photo']) - the way you mentioned this is wrong i think

Comment: Oh, I get your point now. How best do you think I can re-write this line?

Comment: If you are trying to update the image field use ``` profile.emp_photo =request.FILES['emp_photo'] ```rather than ```profile(emp_photo=request.FILES['emp_photo'])```

Comment: `profile.emp_photo=request.FILES['emp_photo]` throws up the error `raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'emp_photo'`

Answer (score 0):

You can think of using  `request.FILES.getlist('emp_photo')`
and additionally check if `emp_photo` key exists by printing it in your code if it holds some value.

Comment: The error  `newPic.save()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'save'` was shown when I tried this method

Comment: this request fetch you list of files, you need to play around with it to achieve required purpose, btw what are you getting if you just print(request.FILES.getlist('emp_photo')) as based on that you have to send req to  emp_photo parameter in your profile() as it accepts emp_photo as single file not in format of list. So it might be getting [0] of it depending upon what is print(request.FILES.getlist('emp_photo')) output.

Comment: I tried `print(request.FILES.getlist('emp_photo'))` in console and it returned `Can't find file (request.FILES.getlist('emp_photo'))`. I guess there is something I am doing wrong which I need to figure out

Comment: there is issue with attaching the file, your request says there is no file attached