# How to Save a ImageField in a model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, imagefield, file-storage

I have a CustomUser Model with following fields

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',blank=True,null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=40)
    dob = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    passportnumber = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
```

I am trying to have a progress bar for the image upload so I have two forms in single page as follows

```
<body>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-3'></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 ">
            <h4>Register</h4>
            <form id="uploadform" method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data action="/upload/">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type=file id="media" name=media ;>
                <input type="submit" onclick='copy_url(document.getElementById("media").files[0].name)'>
            </form>

            <div class="progress">
                <div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="0"
                    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">0%</div>
            </div>
            <form id="registerform"method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <!-- <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>Image</label>
                    <input name="image" type="file" value="">
                </div> -->
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <input id="image" name="image" type="hidden" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>Email address</label>
                    <input name="email" class="form-control" type="email" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>Fullname</label>
                    <input name="fullname" class="form-control" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>Dob</label>
                    <input name="dob" class="form-control" type="date" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>Phonenumber</label>
                    <input name="phonenumber" class="form-control" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>Passportnumber</label>
                    <input name="passportnumber" class="form-control" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input name="username" class="form-control" type="text" value="">
                    <span class="help-block">Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_
                        only.</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input name="password" class="form-control" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <label>Confirm password</label>
                    <input name="confirm_password" class="form-control" type="text" value="">
                </div>
                <!-- <label for="{{ serializer.fullname.id_for_label }}">Fullname:</label>
            <input type="text" id ="{{ serializer.fullname }}"><br/>
            <label for="{{ serializer.dob.id_for_label }}">Dob:</label>
            <input type="date" id ="{{ serializer.dob }}"><br/> -->
                <!-- {% render_form serializer %} -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

After uploading the image. I want that image to be stored in my model for the corresponding user.How do I do that?

I am using ajax for the progress bar

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#uploadform').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($('#uploadform')[0]);

        $.ajax({
            xhr: function(){
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(e){
                    if(e.lengthComputable){
                        console.log('Bytes Loaded :' + e.loaded)
                        console.log('Total Size:' + e.total)
                        console.log('Percentage Uploaded:' + e.loaded/e.total)
                        var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
                        $('#progress-bar').attr('aria-valuenow',percent).css('width',percent+'%').text(percent+'%')
                    }
                })
                return xhr;
            },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/upload/',
            data : formData,
            processData : false,
            contentType : false,
            success : function(response){
                var fs = response
                alert('File uploaded!');
            }
        })
    });
});
```

I tried to pass the location of the image uploaded in form1 say /images/photo.jpeg to the imagefield but it throws error. How do I pass that to the imagefield ???

Comment: Is this a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1308386/6207775 ?

Comment: It is almost same but I am using serializer so while validating serializer.is_valid() I get the following error "the submitted data was not a file. check the encoding type on the form.', code='invalid')] django" I have written the validate_image function in my serializer but before that some default validation by serialzer.is_valid() runs and causes the following error. I am passing the location of the image file to image key like images/photo.jpeg. @Ayushya Thank You