# How to save or upload an image from LOCAL directory to ImageField of database object in DJANGO

Tags: django, django-models, file-upload

I was trying to create some products in ecommerce project in django and i had the data file ready and just wanted to loop throw the data and save to the database with `Product.objects.create(image='', ...)`  but i couldnt upload the images from local directory to database!

I tried these ways:

1

```
with open('IMAGE_PATH', 'rb') as f:
     image = f.read()

Product.objects.create(image=image)
```

2

```
image = open('IMAGE_PATH', 'rb')

Product.objects.create(image=image)
```

3

```
module_dir = dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

for p in products:
    file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, p['image'])
    Product.objects.create()

     product.image.save(
            file_path,
            File(open(file_path, 'rb'))
            )

     product.save()
```

none worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching, I got the answer.
the code to use would be like this:

```
from django.core.files import File

for p in products:
    product = Product.objects.create()
    
    FILE_PATH = p['image']

    local_file = open(f'./APP_NAME/{FILE_PATH}', "rb")
    djangofile = File(local_file)
    product.image.save('FILE_NAME.jpg', djangofile)
    local_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.files import File  
import urllib


result = urllib.urlretrieve(image_url) # image_url is a URL to an image

model_instance.photo.save(
    os.path.basename(self.url),
    File(open(result[0], 'rb'))
    )

self.save()
```

Got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield)