# Copy the contents of an ImageField to a new file path in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django model object that has a few normal attributes, and it has a ImageField for the logo. I want to write a method that'll copy this object to a new object. It's easy enough to instanciate the new object, then loop over all the attributes and copy from the old to new (e.g. `new_object.name = old_object.name`). However if I do that with the logo field (i.e. `new_object.logo = old_object.logo`), both new_object and old_object point to the same file on the harddisk. If you edit the old file, the logo for the new object will change.

What's the best way to have a full/deep copy of the ImageField? I want it to have a different file name and to point to a different file on the disk, but it should have exactly the same content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create a function that is fun on the save signal which copies the image **file** to whereever you want, then creates a new object with a new image field?

**models.py**

```
class ObjectOne(models.Model):
    logo = models.ImageField(...)

class ObjectTwo(models.Model):
    logo = models.ImageField(...)

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from signals import my_signal
post_save.connect(my_signal, dispatch_uid="001")
```

**signals.py**

```
from models. import ObjectOne, ObjectTwo
def my_signal(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if sender is ObjectOne:
        new_obj = ObjectTwo()
        new_obj.logo.save("custom/path/new_filename.jpg",File(open(instance.image.url,"w"))
        new_obj.save()
```

I haven't tested the image copying code but this is the general idea. There is more here:

[Programmatically saving image to Django ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield)

[Django: add image in an ImageField from image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393202/django-add-image-in-an-imagefield-from-image-url)

[how to manually assign imagefield in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811167/how-to-manually-assign-imagefield-in-django)