# Open a remote file via urlopen and add it to a FileField

Tags: python, django

I have a question similar to this:
[how to manually assign imagefield in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811167/how-to-manually-assign-imagefield-in-django)

Except my file is coming from a remote host and I am only given an url, so something like:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    url = models.URLField()
    file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)

class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book

def view(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = BookForm()
        if form.is_valid():
            request = form.instance.source_url
            try:
                f = urlopen(request)
                # ...create open file obj...
                form.instance.local_file.save(form.instance.ref, f.read(), True)

            except Exception:
                print 3
```

How should I turn `f` into an open file object in this case so I can save its contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) it is trivial.

```
import requests
from StringIO import StringIO

r = requests.get(file_url)
f = StringIO(r.content)

# f.read()
```

Finally, as written - your code will lead to problems as you are reassigning `request`, which is passed in. You should change this line `request = form.instance.source_url` to something else like `file_url = from.instance.source_url`.